# What is the name of this book with an adventure on the backside?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification, dragonlance

I'm trying to find a book again that I had decades ago. It was a book for the Dragonlance setting. It had a map on the backside with the city, the inn from the first novel, and the surrounding area. On the map was also a location for a vampire mansion and inside the book were details on the mansion, the vampire, and also info about the different cast members from the book (including background info).

All in all, the book allowed one to play adventures just before the 1st novel was set.

Can someone tell me the name of the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for [Tales of the Lance](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/16961/Tales-of-the-Lance-2e), which had a pull-out poster map and information about vampire [Kryl Shadestalker](https://dragonlance.fandom.com/wiki/Kryl_Shadestalker).

Comment: its the 2nd book of them.. strangely for my hardcopy back then it was 100% on the backside of the book not in the middle.  tnx